# Select2 fire event on mouseenter of results

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to reset a timer that's closing the parent DIV containing a select2-container on mouseleave.

This does not fire:

```
$('.select2-dropdown').on('mouseenter', function(e){
   console.log('in');
   clearInterval( $(this).data('timer') );
});
```

I tried all possible selectors on the DOM but it does not fire.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Select2?

Comment: Where are you setting this handler?

Comment: in document ready a few lines after initializing the select2 - you mean it maybe is not finished yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not appear to be setting this handler correctly.

The dropdown is only generated by Select2 when it opens, and it is removed after it closes. So you can't just set the handler once and forget about it, unless you use event delegation.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.select2-results__option', function(e){
   console.log('in');
   clearInterval( $(this).data('timer') );
});
```

So it will actually catch the event on the `body` and then check if it came from the option in the results.

The other option is to keep your current handler, but bind it during `select2:open` (on the select) instead of `ready` (on the document). This *may* also require unbinding it during `select2:close`.

Comment: thank you VERY much, that of course solved the problem. Doesn't that handler on the body have a negative performance-impact though?

Comment: The handler on the body may have a _slight_ performance impact because it has to check all events that propagate up. But I don't think it's enough to be a huge issue for most.

Comment: thanks. I'll try your 2nd option anyway as I dislike every performance impact, may it be litte :)